# Quiero insertar una parte de mi archivo excel a sql hasta donde yo le indique

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy insertando una información de `Excel` a `SQL` con `OPENROWSET` pero solo quiero una parte de estos datos, es decir hasta donde yo le indique pero no se si esto es posible.

```
SELECT * 
into SA_OCUPACION
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''I:\FTPshare\....,FORMATFILE = 
''I:\FTPshare\.....\OCUP1.XML'',FIRSTROW = 2) AS A
```

'

[image: EN]

Como pueden ver hasta cierta parte empieza una nueva tabla

> (Tenant Name,"Agent Name","Media Type","% Occupancy")

A partir de ahí, ya no quisiera que se inserte

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Sabes que las mayusculas en una publicacion es como gritar no?

Comment: de paso.. sql no es ninguna base de datos.. es un lenguaje de base de datos.. o sea.. a que base estas tratando de importar?

Answer (score 0):

Inlcuye la opción `LASTROW` en la llamada a [`OPENROWSET`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql). La documentación dice:

> LASTROW = última_fila. Especifica el número de la última fila que se va a cargar. El valor predeterminado es 0. Indica la última fila del archivo de datos especificado.

Así, según se puede ver en la imagen, necesitas llegar hasta la fila 268148, asi que el siguiente comando te funcionaría:

```
SELECT * 
into SA_OCUPACION
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'I:\FTPshare\....', FORMATFILE = 
'I:\FTPshare\.....\OCUP1.XML', FIRSTROW = 2, LASTROW = 268148) AS A
```

Comment: WOWWW Muchas graciass lo aplicaré pero intuyo que sí funcionará.Lo máximo mil gracias.

Comment: Una consulta si la ultima fila no siempre es fija , conoces alguna forma de detectar eso ? para insertar el documento.

Comment: Ideal sería pre-procesar ese archivo para que no traiga la información que no te interesa, pero si la tiene que traer, podrías insertar todo en una tabla temporal, hacer un select para _detectar_ la fila donde inicia la información que ya no te interesa y borrar a partir de esa fila, para finalmente insertar la información de esa tabla temporal a la tabla final.